# Exception as Org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses: maxClauseCount is set to XXXX

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-query-syntax

I'm getting exception like below -

ERROR [http-bio-8085-exec-28] org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  - org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024
    at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery.add(BooleanQuery.java:136)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery.add(BooleanQuery.java:127)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ScoringRewrite$1.addClause(ScoringRewrite.java:51)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.ScoringRewrite$1.addClause(ScoringRewrite.java:55)

As per my understanding, This exception comes at QueryTime (when query clauses crosses it's limit here in this case 1024) but can this come at Indexing time ?

I've got this in logs, and not sure which process (indexing / Querying) this is occurring in ?

Thanks.
Dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, there is no query involved in indexing new data, so you shouldn't see this when adding a document.

However, when updating or deleting documents, they may be retrieved with a query (using [`deleteDocuments(Query query)`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#deleteDocuments%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query%29), for example).  It would be unusual for a deletion or update query to be complex enough to generate 1024 clauses, but it could happen.

Much more likely that it is the result of a search query, though.

Answer (score 1):

I've also encountered this error when using `Lucene BooleanQuery`. I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024.
```

The reason is that the query term is beyond the `BooleanQuery` limits. You can solve this using **`BooleanQuery.setMaxClauseCount(10000);`**. However, you should be careful as this may cause an `OutOfMemory` error.